# First run gives subscript out of range error

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

When I run the following code in MS Access I get a subscript out of range error on the first run only. If I click ok on the error and run again it is fine. If I close the database and reopen it I again get the error on the first run.

```
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputTable, "tblOutput", acFormatXLS, "Output.xls", True
Excel.Workbooks("Output.xls").Worksheets("tblOutput").Rows("1:3").Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove 'or xlFormatFromRightOrBelow
Excel.Workbooks("Output.xls").Worksheets("tblOutput").Range("B2") = "data 1"
Excel.Workbooks("Output.xls").Worksheets("tblOutput").Range("D2") = "data 2"
Excel.Workbooks("Output.xls").Worksheets("tblOutput").Range("E2") = "date 3"
Excel.Workbooks("Output.xls").Worksheets("tblOutput").Range("F2") = "data 3"
Excel.Workbooks("Output.xls").Save
```

Comment: Which line gets the error?

Comment: Do you have any other `DoCmd.OutputTo` lines earlier in the same code? I would recommend using `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet` instead.

Comment: The second line, I think it doesn't recognise the Excel workbook on the first run.

Comment: Possibly a timing issue: Put doevents after the 1st line.  The excel file may not be open at the time you attempt to access it.

Comment: Doevents did not help, I tried putting a msgbox in there to force a delay.

Comment: What if you set the workbook to a variable first and test if it exists (at least you'll know that Access can find it)...then refer to the variable for the rest of the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm surprised this works at all, ever. :o

`Excel.Workbooks` refers to the generic Excel class that is referenced in your VBA project, but not to the actual instance of Excel that you started with `DoCmd.OutputTo`.

You need to get the actual object. In your case the easiest method is to use `GetObject()` on the file, I think.

This works for me:

```vb
Sub TestOutput()

    Dim wb As Excel.Workbook

    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputTable, "tblOutput", acFormatXLS, "D:\Output.xls", True
    Set wb = GetObject("D:\Output.xls")

    wb.Worksheets("tblOutput").Rows("1:3").Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

End Sub
```